# Upgrade to Windows 10 - v1607: Does it conflict with McAfee VSE?

Tags: windows-update, anti-virus, windows-10-v1607

First a little background. When I upgraded from Windows 8 to 10 last year, I had to remove McAfee VirusScan Enterprise (VSE) prior to the upgrade. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reinstall it after the upgrade was done, because McAfee didn't have a compatible version of its software yet. Or, at least I couldn't obtain it. So, I had to wait a few months before I was able to install it again.

Now, Windows is prompting me to upgrade to v1607 (the anniversary upgrade). Of course, the same message appears, I have to deinstall McAfee VSE first. Does anybody know whether my current version will still work after the upgrade? And if not, whether McAfee already has a compatible version available?

Comment: Please provide tips to improve my question if you downvote. Thx.

Comment: @Ramhound My comment wasn't addressed at you specifically. I would have used an @ in that case. So please don't take it personally. Furthermore, I wasn't calling out anyone on voting. I understand it is anonymous and that comments are not required, but all I did was kindly ask for some advice to improve my post. As you can see, I'm new to this SE community. So getting downvoted without any tips to improve my post is kind of disappointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is mentioned on the [MacAfee Knowledgebase website](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=kb51111):

> **WARNING**: VSE 8.8 Patch 7 and earlier are NOT compatible with the Microsoft Windows 10 Anniversary Update. Support for the Windows 10 Anniversary Update is included in VSE 8.8 Patch 8. DO NOT install VSE 8.8 Patch 7 or earlier on systems running the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. Likewise, DO NOT upgrade systems running VSE 8.8 Patch 7 or earlier to the Windows 10 Anniversary Update.

According to this information you shall not upgrade to Windows 10 Anniversary Update if you're running VSE 8.8 Patch 7.

Although the same page has info about VSE 8.8 Patch 8 which is compatible with Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607 build 14393). If you have a chance to upgrade to the new patch, then proceed with update.

Comment: Thx! That's a good reference link, and all the info I needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the version my employer distributes is still VSE 8.8 Patch 6, so I'll have to wait a bit.